# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine error

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office

I have two different .Net(c#) applications, both using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.

When I install both of them on a clean machine - Windows 8.1 x64 - no office or anything else installed - both give me the "...OLEDB.12.0 provider not registered..." error message when I try to read data from MS Access DB, which, of course, is expected since I don't have the runtime installed.

The weird thing occurs when I install the MS Access Runtime. If I install the x64 version, application A reads the msaccess or excel files without any problem, but application B still get the "...not registered" error message.
Then I go and uninstall MS Access Runtime x64 and install the x32. Guess what? Application A stops working and application B works...

I have no idea what is going on there.

Application A uses the following connection string:

`protected override void ConnectBase()
        {
            try
            {
                m_connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + m_filePath;
                m_connection = new OleDbConnection(m_connectionString);
                m_connection.Open();
                m_command = new OleDbCommand("", m_connection);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ConnectionException(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }`

Application B uses this:

```
        protected override void LoadTableNames()
    {
        m_tableNames = new List<string>();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DataSource))
            return;

        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + DataSource;
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            DataTable allTables = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

            for (int i = 0; i < allTables.Rows.Count; i++)
                m_tableNames.Add(allTables.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

They both have target framework set to 4.0
and they both have platform target to **AnyCPU**
They are both ClassLibrary (dlls)

- The exe that calls Application A has platform target set to x86
- The exe that calls Application B also has platform target set to x86

What am I missing here ? anyone?

Comment: have you tried setting platform target to 32-bit for both instead of any cpu?  Sometimes windows has issues with that flag.

Comment: Could you clarify which portion are DLL's and which is the executable (EXE)? While I note you've said the target platform for each executable is x86, the symptoms you describe sound very much like those of a 64-bit executable versus a 32-bit executable. Each will require the corresponding version of any drivers it may need (32-bit driver for 32-bit app, 64-bit driver for 64-bit.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms you are describing - "x64 Access runtime:App A works/App B fails, x32 Access runtime: App A fails/App B works" sound very much like App A is a 64-bit application, and App B is a 32-bit application. Each version will require the "bitness" of driver corresponding to its executable type, so to get both working, you may well need to install *both* the 32- and 64-bit runtimes (drivers).

Comment: i've run into this same issue and this was the only solution that worked

Comment: I would like to avoid having to install the 2 versions of the runtime. How do I tell App B is 32 bit? if that's the case I would prefer to change it , so both my apps are either 64 or 32 bit. as long as they are the same. I thought that setting the target platform to x86 on both apps would do it, but apparently not. what am my still missing?

Comment: Ideally, what you did *should* be the proper solution, but your experience with the apps suggests something in that vein wasn't done correctly....I'd double check the settings for each application and recompile each executable and try again.

Comment: I got it! I was checking the configuration on Debug mode (which had the target set to x86 ) but I was building in Release mode (which didn't have the target set to Any CPU). I can't believe I spent so much time for that little detail! :/ Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's awesome! Glad I was able to help.